# Weird phonebook entries!

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, htc

I had my HTC Pico phone with android 2.3 repaired because a shattered glass.

On getting it back, I found out that there are no contacts in my phone as well as in the SIM, but there are some contacts with my Google account. Upon selecting this option, my phone book displayed a few contacts, which I never synced to my Google account. How did these random contacts get associated with my Google account?

Comment: Easiest explanation: If you sent your device to repair with even the SIM card included, and not factory-resetted, some service guy may have played with it. Not to blame somebody, but that's the easiest explanation to it.